# Where can I find the Forest Cover Density (FCD) mapping software

Tags: forest-ecology

Does anyone know where I can find the latest Forest Cover Density (FCD) mapper software, as introduced in **[this paper](http://www.tropecol.com/pdf/open/PDF_43_1/43104.pdf)**.

Comment: Not sure about the software but in ArcGIS 10.1 it might possible please check http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015w00000056000000

Comment: Have you tried emailing the corresponding author? He's still at Nagaoka UT.

Comment: Or ITTO (www.itto.int) who funded its development.

Answer (score 1):

> The latest version of the Mapper, version 2 was revised as part of ITTO project PD 13/97 Rev. 1 (F) in 2003. It is available from ITTO on a CD-ROM.

ref: http://espace.library.uq.edu.au/view/UQ:8454/n19_Jack_Using_F.pdf

[International Tropical Timber Organization (ITTO)](https://www.itto.int/)